# Keep a view always on top (Don't scroll with keyboard) in IQKeyboardManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using `IQKeyboardManager` to keep the text fields to go up after typing with the keyboard.

I don't want to scroll to a specific view even when clicked on the text field. Below is the screenshot of the design. I want the 'header' to remain on top.

[image: inspector layout for the view]

From their documentation, [there is a way to keep the navigation bar remain on top.](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/MANUAL%20MANAGEMENT.md)

Comment: I would suggest, to achieve this functionality, disable IQKeyboardmanager for this view controller and manually move your textfield up when keyboard appears.

Comment: I'm new to this. That's why I chose this library. No way?

Comment: @GijoVarghese is there `tableview` in view?

Comment: @BhavinRamani yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the IQKeyboardManager for your ViewController.

for that,

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().disableInViewControllerClass(ViewController.self)
```

And In that viewController write the following code. It will move your view up as per keyboard height

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
}
```

Now you want your "**HEADER**" view remain on TOP then,

Do like this :

**

> YourViewController.view -> [headerView][contentView]

**

Put **textfield** in [contentView] And change [contentView].y instead of Self.view in above code.

Comment: what is 'login' here?

Comment: @GijoVarghese Replace `login` with your `ViewController` name.

Comment: Yes. Got it working. But the problem is that, clicking the text field everything in the screen goes up. Including a view at the top. Is it possible to keep that view remain on top always?

Comment: yes, you can do it. In your view, take 2 Views. 1 is HEADER. and 2. Content. and instead of changing  self.view  frame use Content and change its frame.

Comment: so literally, you just saying "don't use IQKeyboardManager, manage constraints yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the `IQKeyboardManager` for your `viewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Login.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Login.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

Handle keyboard:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.table_view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.table_view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    }
```

Remove observer:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers from @Wolverine and @Bhavin Ramani were great: the best way to keep your **custom header** staying at top is to manually handle your keyboard (according to IQKeyboardSwift author's [comment](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/500#issuecomment-465976227)). If you use iOS default navigation bar, it seems it's handled for you by the library.

Here I just want to share some updates on this topic, for my future reference, as the answers are a bit old and some Swift syntax has changed. Code below is written in Xcode 13.2, targeting iOS 13+.

Firstly, you want to disable KQKeyboardManager by doing

```swift
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
```

Please note this lines only disables **moving text field up feature**, other IQKeyboard features such as resign on touch outside, auto tool bar, and etc., are not disabled by this line, this is usually what you want.

Then, you register keyboard events observer in view controller's `viewDidLoad`, remove observers in `deinit`.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
                                               object: nil)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

Next, add view moving up/down methods for keyboard show/hide.

```swift
    @objc private func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {     
        if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            print("keyboardSize.height", keyboardSize.height)
            // using the right key here is important, because 
            // keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey is an user info key 
            // to retrieve the keyboard’s frame at the END of its animation.

            // here you move up the views you need to move up
            // if you use auto layout, update the corresponding constraints
            // or you update the views' frame.origin.y
            // you may want to do the updates within a 0.25s animation
        }
    }

    @objc private func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            // reset views to their original position on keyboard dismiss
        }
    }
```

You may also want to enable/disable auto tool bar, as it could make your keyboard height unstable.

```swift
// in viewDidLoad set to false, in deinit set back to true (if you need it)
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```