# How to hide Toolbar in IQKeyboardManager iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios-keyboard-extension, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using the [IQKeyboardManger](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library to scroll text fields when started typing using the keyboard, but I don't want to display the default toolbar from their library. Below is the code I've used.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.chatTextField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];  //This will remove toolbar which have done button.

        self.chatTextField.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 8; //This will modify default distance between textField and keyboard. For exact value, please manually check how far your textField from the bottom of the page. Mine was 8pt.    

    }
```

[image]

Comment: [IQToolbar handling](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/PROPERTIES%20&%20FUNCTIONS.md#iqtoolbar-handling)

Comment: @BhavinRamani where can I enable this value?

Comment: in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: Is your code snippet a collection of Objective-c and Swift? O.o

Comment: @AhmadF Great! That one worked. Mine is in Swift 3

Comment: @BhavinRamani Can you pls help me with this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124131/keep-a-view-always-on-top-dont-scroll-with-keyboard-in-iqkeyboardmanager

Comment: @BhavinRamani oops someone posted the answer before you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set IQKeyboardManager below properties.

I assume you have enabled the IQKeyboardManager in didFinishLaunch of app delegate like this

```
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

**shouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder** to `false` ==>  If you want to hide placeholder toolbar section

**shouldHidePreviousNext** to `false` ==> If you want to hide next and prev button and so on.

You can enable the settings in **didFinishLaunch** of **AppDelegate** like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder = false
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldHidePreviousNext = false


    return true
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124131/keep-a-view-always-on-top-dont-scroll-with-keyboard-in-iqkeyboardmanager

Comment: I want to hide previous/next button but [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] shouldHidePreviousNext] = YES; throwing me an error shouldHidePreviousNext is not available... Any help appreciated...

Comment: shouldHidePreviousNext has deprecated, in this place use previousNextDisplayMode

Comment: to hide next previous key use:-

IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().previousNextDisplayMode = IQPreviousNextDisplayMode.alwaysHide

Comment: can I hide toolbar for just a specific textfield?

Answer (score 12):

You can enable or disable the toolbar in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

For more info see [Properties and functions usage](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/PROPERTIES%20&%20FUNCTIONS.md#iqtoolbar-handling)

Comment: can I hide toolbar for just a specific textfield?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**
You must use `shouldResignOnTouchOutside` to resign textField if touched outside of `UITextField`/`UITextView`.

Add this in your `ViewController` if you want it in an specific `ViewController` or to override all your application in the file `AppDelegate`.

Inside the method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
}
```

Comment: This was flagged as a low quality post. Please add some explanatory text and clean up the formatting of the code block.

Answer (score 5):

This is the way to do it for an individual view controller:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledToolbarClasses = [YourViewController.self]
    }
}
```

And to [prevent the vc from rising](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/252#issuecomment-362509401) when IQKeyboardManager raises it when the keyboard is present:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.disabledDistanceHandlingClasses.append(YourViewController.self)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to hide for a specific controller, you can do like this :

- `import IQKeyboardManagerSwift` in your the desired View Controller.
- Add this extension :

  ```
  // MARK: - Helper
  extension <#yourViewController#> {

    private func keyboardManagerVisible(_ state: Bool) {
      IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = state
    }
  }
  ```
- Implement this in the life cycle :

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      self.keyboardManagerVisible(false)
  }

  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

      self.keyboardManagerVisible(true)
  }
  ```

Comment: this works but if pushing and popping a vc you should use `viewWillAppear` to hide the keyboard instead of `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.0 and above For hide previous Next

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
```

Swift 4.0 and above For toolbar

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.1, Xcode 11**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, IQKeyboardManager (6.3.0)**

You can call this setup function from your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate:

```
private func setupKeyboardManager() {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared().previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
}
```

Feel free to add any other customisation you need in this method, such as `shouldResignOnTouchOutside` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the toolbar just for the specific `UITextField` you can do it using:

```
textField.keyboardToolbar.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Enable IQKeyboardManager in Swift 4

Maybe try this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //Your other code here       

    // -- enable IQKeyboardManager --
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
    
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift4.2**

```
 //Add these line into didFinishLaunch
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true        
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```