# Hide next previous button in IQKeyboardManager in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using `IQKeyboardManager` and I want to hide the next/previous button from the keyboard...

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124364/how-to-hide-toolbar-in-iqkeyboardmanager-ios-swift-3).

I tried with this code:

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] shouldHidePreviousNext] = YES;
```

but the `shouldHidePreviousNext` property is not available in the library... How can we achieve this? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: the property is modified,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**shouldHidePreviousNext**  has deprecated, in this place use `previousNextDisplayMode`

> **IQPreviousNextDisplayModeDefault**:      Show NextPrevious when there are more than 1 textField otherwise hide.
>
> **IQPreviousNextDisplayModeAlwaysHide**:   Do not show NextPrevious buttons in any case.
>
> **IQPreviousNextDisplayModeAlwaysShow**:   Always show nextPrevious buttons, if there are more than 1 textField then both buttons will be visible but will be shown as disabled.

you can access with the property of

> @property(nonatomic, assign) **IQPreviousNextDisplayMode** **previousNextDisplayMode**;

use

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] previousNextDisplayMode] = IQPreviousNextDisplayModeAlwaysHide;
```

Answer (score 1):

`shouldHidePreviousNext` is deprecated, Use the below

Try this:

**Objective-C**

```
[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].previousNextDisplayMode = IQPreviousNextDisplayModeAlwaysHide;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** solution for the above answers:

```
 IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
```

Answer (score 0):

This property is deprecated and modifies with the new one.`IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide` Hope you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldHidePreviousNext` deprecated, use `previousNextDisplayMode`

Objective-C

```
[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager].previousNextDisplayMode = IQPreviousNextDisplayModeAlwaysHide;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you working on a swift project just write this in your code.

```html
IQKeyboardManager.shared.previousNextDisplayMode = .alwaysHide
```