# iqkeyboard toolbar run to the top

Tags: ios, input, textfield, toolbar

On the login page, use the account password. When you click to log in, the Apple system will pop up the actionSheet to save the password. Click Cancel, and the toolBar will be displayed at the top of the screen (below the status bar). not only ios13, ios12 same.[image]

Comment: have anyone meet with it?

Comment: Can you share a chunk of you code?

Comment: Try this `IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false` and also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124364/how-to-hide-toolbar-in-iqkeyboardmanager-ios-swift-3)

Comment: It is possible to hide the toolbar, but all the functions of iqkeyboard are also wrong. This is easy to reproduce, as long as the save password of the Apple system (for new accounts and passwords) is popped up in the application, or half of the screen has been saved by clicking the keychain Account password actionSheet. After that, the toolbar will be incorrectly displayed at the top of the screen.

Comment: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1647