# IQKeyboardManager - keeping the UINavigationBar sticky to the top

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, iqkeyboardmanager

I'm using `IQKeyboardManager` in Swift to handle the keyboard in my app (it's a chat app and the `UICollectionView` and the `UITextField` should move up and down according to the keyboard's position). It's working great.

My only problem is that it moves the whole view up, including the `UINavigationBar` and that's why it looks very weird. I want the `UINavigationBar` to remain sticky on the top of the screen.

Any idea how can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: try with `self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = false;`

Comment: are you using autoulayout

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Does't work

Comment: @Kuldeep Default with some left and right buttons

Comment: @RahulGUsai Yes

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124131/keep-a-view-always-on-top-dont-scroll-with-keyboard-in-iqkeyboardmanager

Comment: Post the same on their git repo. Also check for existing Closed issues in the repo.

Comment: @FS.O6 I would suggest you to disable IQKeyboardManager in your chat screen and implement it in your own way. because it's hard to implement chat screen with IqKeyboardManager.

Comment: @FS.O6 You have to change the view hierarchy of the textField. Thats how I solved the same issue my project.

Comment: @DilipTiwari change the view hierarchy of textfield and textview.

Comment: could u tell because i have taken a custom navigation and below that their is a tableview at bottom below tableview their is textview and send button

Comment: @Kuldeep i already tried this but the problem Navigation it at original position but textview and send button is not shows when we scroll then it shows

Comment: i have a custom UIView(used as Navigation Bar) , then i have a tableview below Navigation Bar, then i have a TextView and Send Button at bottom below tableview like Whats app @Kuldeep